# MySQL Query get minimal distance (nearest neighbour)

Tags: mysql, performance, geospatial, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to find the nearest neighbour to the GPS coordinate (52,14) in a geospatial database with the following query:

```
SELECT
geonameid,
SQRT(POW(latitude-52, 2) + POW(longitude-14, 2)) as distance
FROM table
WHERE
latitude >= 52-1 AND latitude <= 52+1 AND
longitude >= 14-1 AND longitude <= 14+1
ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 1
```

The table is created with:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
`geonameid` int,
`latitude` DECIMAL(5,2),
`longitude` DECIMAL(5,2),
...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
CREATE INDEX g USING BTREE ON table(latitude);
CREATE INDEX b USING BTREE ON table(longitude);
```

Although i have created indices on both latitude and longitude columns the above query runs very slow (~60 seconds: Table has around 3.4 mil entries).

When i omit the ordering by distance, the query is very fast but is not guaranteed to give me the nearest neighbour of course.

How can i improve the performance of the query? I thought using WHERE on latitude and longitude column, to limit result set, does reduce runtime alot. For some reason it does not, do you know why?

Comment: You could try MySQL's [spatial extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html). You can index and optimize for geoqueries.